# Can't deploy to Blackberry 10 Simulator using WebWorks

Tags: html, cordova, blackberry-10

I have now followed all the Blackberry documention found [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/setting_up_your_tools.html) and [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/beta/creating_your_first_app.html). Yet some how I keep getting the following error:

```
[BUILD]   Populating application source
[BUILD]   Parsing config.xml
[BUILD]   Generating output files
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to %HOME%/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
[WARN]    Failed to find debug token. If you have an existing debug token, please copy it to %HOME%/.cordova/blackberry10debugtoken.bar. To generate a new debug token, execute the 'run' command.
```

I have created the bar using this link [here](https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/gold/running_your_app_on_a_device.html) (which wasn't even specified in the links above) Please can anyone explain this or point to a tutorial the gets one up and running to a hello world app for blackberry WebWorks as the Blackberry links really don't help

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to find useful instructions either, however I have the native SDK installed  alongside the Momentics IDE and it has a wizard that created all the necessary for me:

1. Create a new BB10 project
2. Right click on the project root node in the Project Explorer
3. Open BlackBerry Tools and then Configure Targets

   > > A wizard will start allowing you to create the CSK and BAR files, and also deploy them to your devices if there is no CSK in C:\USERS[User]\AppData\Local\Research In Motion
   > >     If the CSK already exists in the path above you'll be able to create and install Debug Tokens with your existing CSK.
4. After you've created the token I had to copy it to C:\Users[User].cordova and rename it to blackberry10debugtoken.bar to get the build in the WebWorks UI to work.

However, though I've now got an installed DebugToken on my simulator, and the Webworks UI happily builds the project, the Build and Install action fails with an error message as follows:

```
fs.js:418
  binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path),
          ^
TypeError: path must be a string
    at Object.fs.open (fs.js:418:11)
    at Object.fs.readFile (fs.js:206:6)
    at _self.findConnectedSimulator (D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\lib\target-utils.js:190:12)
    at Object.async.series.ip (D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\lib\run-utils.js:48:17)
    at D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:561:25
    at iterate (D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:131:13)
    at Object.async.eachSeries (D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:147:9)
    at Object.async.series (D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:560:19)
    at Object.getTargetName (D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\lib\run-utils.js:45:15)
    at fn (D:\WebWorks\HelloWorld\platforms\blackberry10\cordova\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:579:34)
```

I'd be grateful for anyone who is able to further my discovery and make the WebWorks UI work without having to install Momentics & the native SDK, or to get the deployment to the simulator working...